How to display content only when hovering over an element
I attempted to replicate the behavior on GitHub, where hovering over headings shows an icon.
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug'
import rehypeAutolinkHeadings from "rehype-autolink-headings";

type Params = {
  params: {
    slug: string;
  };
};
export default async function PostPage({ params }: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {


  const source = await getPostBySlug(params.slug); // Destructure frontMatter correctly here
  const components = useMDXComponents({});
  const { content, frontmatter } = await compileMDX<{ title: string, subtitle: string, part: string }>({
    source: source,
    components: components,
    options: {
      parseFrontmatter: true,
      mdxOptions: {
        remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm, remarkToc],
        rehypePlugins: [rehypeSlug, [rehypeAutolinkHeadings, {
          behaviour: "wrap", properties: {
            className: ['section_heading'],
          },
        }]]
        // ... other options
      }
    },

  });
  console.log(content)
  return (
    <article className="px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
      <div className="relative max-w-3xl mx-auto">
        <div className="prose prose-lg prose-p:mb-2 text-justify dark:prose-invert max-w-3xl">
          <div
            className="prose-strong:text-gray-900 dark:prose-em:text-slate-400 dark:prose-strong:text-slate-400 prose-em:text-gray-900">
            {content}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
}

I have used rehypeAutolinkHeadings and wrap with
behaviour: "wrap", 
properties: {
   className: ['section_heading'],
},

and added the class as
.section_heading::after {
  content: "#";
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

however i wanted to show the section_heading only when hovered. The hash is shown every time but i want it to be displayed when the header is hover.
And instead of the using the content can we add the lucide-react icon?


I got the solution as answered here, https://github.com/orgs/rehypejs/discussions/101, I removed other property and just used the rehypeAutolinkHeadings and added the css, it shows the link icon on hover only, and it is clickable.
const { content, frontmatter } = await compileMDX<{ title: string, subtitle: string, part: string }>({
    source: source,
    components: components,
    options: {
      parseFrontmatter: true,
      mdxOptions: {
        remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm, remarkToc],
        rehypePlugins: [rehypeSlug, rehypeAutolinkHeadings]
        // ... other options
      }
    },

  });

:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):hover span.icon.icon-link {
  display: inline;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.775 3.275a.75.75 0 001.06 1.06l1.25-1.25a2 2 0 112.83 2.83l-2.5 2.5a2 2 0 01-2.83 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 3.5 3.5 0 004.95 0l2.5-2.5a3.5 3.5 0 00-4.95-4.95l-1.25 1.25zm-4.69 9.64a2 2 0 010-2.83l2.5-2.5a2 2 0 012.83 0 .75.75 0 001.06-1.06 3.5 3.5 0 00-4.95 0l-2.5 2.5a3.5 3.5 0 004.95 4.95l1.25-1.25a.75.75 0 00-1.06-1.06l-1.25 1.25a2 2 0 01-2.83 0z"></path></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  width: 0.8em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* optional: nice icon hover transitions */
:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):hover span.icon.icon-link:hover {
  background-size: 0.9em;
  height: 0.9em;
  width: 0.9em;
  filter: invert(0.1);
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
}

